# Java game: shooting bullets in a simple game

Tags: java, swing

I'm kind of new to java.im trying to write a simple game which it has a player and enemies and when you press some keys like "space", the player most shoot a bullet in right direction but i don't know how to render bullet in game. Actually it doesn't appear and doesn't move in Game.

**Shooting system**

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Bullet {
    GamePanel panel;//Game panel
    Rectangle hitBox;//Bullet
    public int x,y,width,height;
    boolean Shoot;
    public Bullet(int x , int y ,GamePanel panel)
    {
        this.panel = panel;
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        height=15;
        width=15;
        hitBox = new Rectangle(x,y,width,height);
    }

    public void set()
    {
        if(Shoot) // where I have problem which Bullet doesn't move or doesn't appear
            move();
    }

    public void move()
    {
        x=x+10;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D gtd)
    {
        gtd.setColor(Color.RED);
        gtd.fillRect(x,y,width,height);
    }

}
```

**Game Panel which sets Game Objects**

```
package com.company;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    Player player;
    Timer gameTimer;
    Bullet bullet;

    public GamePanel(){
        
        player = new Player(400,300,this);
        bullet = new Bullet(player.x, player.y, this);
       
        gameTimer = new Timer();
        gameTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                player.set();
        bullet.move();
                repaint();

            }
        },100,15);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D gtd = (Graphics2D) g;
        player.draw(gtd);
        bullet.draw(gtd);

    }


    void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getKeyChar()=='w')
            player.keyUp=true;
        if(e.getKeyChar()=='a')
            player.keyLeft=true;
        if(e.getKeyChar()=='s')
            player.keyDown=true;
        if(e.getKeyChar()=='d')
            player.keyRight=true;
        if(e.getKeyChar()=='t')
            bullet.Shoot=true;

    }

    void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getKeyChar()=='w')
            player.keyUp=false;
        if(e.getKeyChar()=='a')
            player.keyLeft=false;
        if(e.getKeyChar()=='s')
            player.keyDown=false;
        if(e.getKeyChar()=='d')
            player.keyRight=false;
        if(e.getKeyChar()=='t')
            bullet.Shoot=false;

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Cuystom painting is done by overriding `paintComponent()` , not paint() 2) you need to invoke `super.paintComponent(...)` to clear the background first 3) Don't use an AWT Timer. Instead use a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). 4) Don't use a KeyListener. Instead use `Key Bindings`. See: [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you're calling `bullet.move();` continuously in the Timer in your `GamePanel` class. Apart from that I'm not entirely sure how you're fetching keyboard input. Your `GamePanel` class contains the methods a `KeyListener` usually would utilize, but the class does not implement a `KeyListener`, but an `ActionListener`, which isn't being used in your code.

So what you should be doing is:

- Verify that your `keyPressed` and `keyReleased` functions are actually being called when a keyboard button is pressed, and if they aren't, you should implement a `KeyListener` instead of an `ActionListener` in the `GamePanel` class
- Make sure that `bullet.move();` is only being called when it should be, as it's currently being called on every iteration of your timer

Comment: Apart from the things stated above, there are other problems you might run into later regarding your code. Later in your progress, when you'll start utilizing the hitbox of the Bullet class, the hitbox and the actual position of the bullet won't match up, as you're declaring the hitbox variable only once in the Bullets constructor.